# Variable Length array forbidden in ISO C++ error in sublime text 3

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14, iso

**I recently changed my C++ compiler**, and I am experiencing this strange error that says **ISO C++ forbids variable length array**. 
I distinctly remember that this error was not encountered by my previous compiler. Here is my code snippet that I wrote just to check the reliability of this new compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}


In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:8:9: error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'a' [-Wvla]
int a[n]={0};
```

You see even when user is taking input in 'n', the compiler states that the array is having variable length.
**Suggestions regarding other compiler version are also welcome!**

Comment: It's exactly what the error says. Standard C++ forbids arrays with lengths that aren't known at compile time. Some compilers have extensions that allow VLAs, but they usually aren't a good idea.

Comment: [Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of C++. Some compilers might add it as a non-standard extension. Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the VLA with a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin>>n;
    std::vector<int> a(n);  // was VLA: int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        std::cin>>a[i];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        std::cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}
```

Comment: [std::vector<T,Allocator>::vector (constructor)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Answer (score 1):

Your new compiler is correct: variable-length arrays are *not* allowed in standard `C++`! (GNU `g++` allows them as an extension). See here: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/10871073)

You should modify your code to use the `std::vector` type, instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> // Definitions for the std::vector types
//using namespace std; // This can cause problems - better only "using" specifics:
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    size_t n; // You CAN use "int" but "size_t" is more accurate here
    cin >> n;
//  int a[n]; // Forbidden in standard C++
    std::vector<int> a(n); // Declare "a" as a vector with "n" elements
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i]; // You can still use the "[i]" syntax to access the elements
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not valid in standard C++. As per C++ standard, array size must be a constant expression. Variable lenghth arrays are not allowed in C++ because C++ provides std::vector for that. C standard allows VLA(variable length arrays) while C++ does not.